# AJAX JSON Call Failure

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I am doing a AJAX call pulling JSON data from a specific site but for some reason I am receiving and error before the call.

Error message:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null at
>   script.js:2

Code:

```
var ajaxtest = document.getElementById("dmeo");

ajaxtest.addEventListener("click",function() {
var ourRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
ourRequest.open("GET","https://learnwebcode.github.io/json-example/animals-1.json")//post if you want to send data
ourRequest.onload = function(){
   // console.log(ourRequest.responseText);//test logging to console.
var ourData = JSON.parse(ourRequest.responseText);
console.log(ourData[0]);
};
ourRequest.send();
});
```

Comment: You spelled demo dmeo

Comment: This was one of those moments where I asked before paying attention and working it out. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED! OK what I ended up doing was just putting it into a onclick event and it works.

```
function Makecall(){
var ourRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
ourRequest.open("GET","https://learnwebcode.github.io/json-example/animals-1.json")//post if you want to send data
ourRequest.onload = function(){
   // console.log(ourRequest.responseText);//test logging to console.
var ourData = JSON.parse(ourRequest.responseText);
console.log(ourData[0]);
};
ourRequest.send();
};
```

Comment: makes zero sense why putting it into a function would work.... There was another issue that you actually fixed

Comment: Yea, I accidentally added the demo id instead of the button id as well.

Answer (score -1):

typo? var ajaxtest = document.getElementById("dmeo");
should be **"demo"**?

Comment: Yea thanks, that was the an issue as well but I changed it by doing an onclick event and adding the onclick event to my button in html. This was one of those moments where I asked before paying attention and working it out. Sorry about that.